# Couldn't find [MODEL] without an Id : Rails 4 custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, friendly-id

I'm trying to create a JSON feed for certain data to pull into a graph I have in a partial. I keep running into "Couldn't find Dam without an Id", and none of the answers on SO seem to have the fix. My params seem to be passing through fine, and I'm a bit perplexed.

routes.rb

```
require "resque/server"
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"

  root 'home#index'
  get 'about', to: 'home#about'

  resources :dams, only: [:index, :show] do
      get 'count_data', to: 'dams#count_data'
    resources :fish_counts, only: [:index, :show]
  end

  resources :fish
end
```

custom action in the dams_controller.rb:

```
    def count_data
      @dam = Dam.includes(:fish_counts, :fish).friendly.find(params[:id])
      @fish_counts = FishCount.for_year(Date.today.year).where("dam_id =?",  @dam.id).limit(200).order(count_date: :desc)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
          render json: {:fish_counts => @fish_counts}
        }
      end
  end
```

I have tried using the id instead of the `friendly.find`, and get the same result. I have success if I delete the `@dam` line and manually add in a `@dam.id` to the `@fish_counts`instance.

Why is the instance variable not picking up the parameters being passed to it? And in situations like this, how would I debug? `raise params.inspect` seems to have just shown me that the proper params are passing through.

Thanks

*edit*

Here's the console output when I search w/o friendly.find:

```
Started GET "/dams/3/count_data.json" for ::1 at 2015-08-15 18:11:04 -0700
Processing by DamsController#count_data as JSON
Parameters: {"dam_id"=>"3"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Dam without an ID):
app/controllers/dams_controller.rb:15:in `count_data'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see in the stack trace that there is no :id in params, but :dam_id, so you should use it like this :

```
@dam = Dam.includes(:fish_counts, :fish).find(params[:dam_id])
```

Comment: I was staring at it and it just hit me, came back to answer my own and see you got it right. Thanks! Will accept.